# Redirect issues

Tags: asp-classic, iis-6

Whoever wrote the navigation for the site I’m currently working on (classic asp) points the navigation links to a folder, then inside to folder has an index.asp file, so the urls will look something like this www.mysite.com/myfolder/mysubfolder

Now, when watch the page load using httpfox, I notice that the first entry is a 302 redirect to the same address with a “/” on the end, so www.mysite.com/myfolder gets redirected to www.mysite.com/myfolder/ (note the / on the end). 
I’m not to worried that it’s a 302 since its in the admin section of the site, but when I forward the host headers from ISA server, for an https request, its being redirected from https://www.mysite.com/myfolder to http://www.mysite.com:443/myfolder/ and causing all kinds of problems.

Anyway, I can’t seem to find any code making this redirect happen, so does IIS 6 do this because the url points to a folder? Or do I need to comb through the code more closely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is not in the code.

the redirect happens because there is no url "https://www.mysize.com/myfolder".

correct urls look like this: "https://www.mysize.com/myfolder/"

so the last / is important and only with this you have a valid url!

the webserver now is cute enough to automatically send a "302 found (originally temporary redirect, but now commonly used to specify redirection for unspecified reason)" status code.

just add the / to the links and you're fine